# Jest output is not rendered as expected in Storybook

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, storybook

I am using Jest addon in Storybook.
https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/jest

From the tutorial, it illustrates the test result in a prettier manner:

[image]

While in my implementation, the result is plain text:

[image]

Please advise how to configure.

```
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react'; // <- or your view layer
import { withTests } from '@storybook/addon-jest';
 
import results from '../.jest-test-results.json';
 
addDecorator(
  withTests({
    results,
  })
);
```

Comment: Curious if you ever got this sorted out @BayOtter

Comment: @EarlePoole Unfortunately not.

Answer (score 1):

I think the screenshot is out of date, unfortunately. I'm seeing the same behaviour with Vue JS components